# Aspects of php include (parsing)

Tags: php, seo, html-parsing

Is it safe to use php include to include aspects which are vital to the semantic meaning of web pages, for things like search engines.

For instance can you have the `<h1></h1>` headers for your pages all siphoned off to an include? Will google spiders, just as an example, be actually able to see these headers? Is there a type of ... passive parsing... if you will, which won't see html that is dependent upon the execution of scripting?

Or is such exclusion exclusive to client side scripting such as javascript?

Comment: Google doesn't look at your PHP code, or the files it's split across: it looks at the HTML rendered by that code for the page

Comment: I would only add that if Google could look at your PHP code then I could do it as well. Only I 'd prefer to look at the configuration file that holds the passwords.

Comment: So the manner it is delivered to something like google would be the same manner in which it is delivered to a normal user's browser that lands on the page? So the server side processing will execute as reliably for crawlers as it will for users?

Comment: @Duncan: Exactly. And that manner is called [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http).

Comment: @Duncan You can verify this fact for yourself with Google Webmaster Tools, which allow you to fetch a page like Google does. See here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587

Comment: Could the overhead generated by increased http fetch requests have any substantial negative bearing on this?

Comment: What increased http fetch requests? Your includes/requires don't use http requests; they filesystem requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google should NEVER see the raw PHP code, because that'd mean your server is misconfigured. The server-side language/processes you're using to build the web page are irrelevant to the end-user, all they should EVER see is html.

Since all a spider sees is that html, it doesn't matter if you're serving it from a plain old .html file, a .php file, a .whatever_extension_you_want file, etc... as long as it LOOKS like a web page when it arrives on the client.

e.g. you could go to an ludicrous extreme and have every single **CHARACTER** of a web page done with nothing but single char includes,e.g.

less_than.txt:

```
<
```

h.txt:

```
h
```

t.txt:

```
t
```

m.txt:

```
m
```

l.txt:

```
l
```

greater_than.txt

```
>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
include('less_than.txt');
include('h.txt');
include('t.txt');
include('m.txt');
include('l.txt');
include('greater_than.txt');
```

Hideously ugly, ludicrously inefficient, but here's what the user will see in their browser's "view source":

```
<html>
```

Comment: Although I will add that if the extension is .html and it includes <?php foo ?> whatever parsing it will read the php, albeit as faulty xml/html

Comment: @duncan: depends on the server configuration. it's trivial to make .html extensions be parsed as php. file extensions in urls mean very little today. it's simply a convention that php scripts use .php. A goofy sysadmin could map `.exe` to the php parser and make things like `http://example.com/reboot.exe` be their default document.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what you asked, try the code...

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php include("header.php"); ?>
  <p><?php echo $superhero;?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<h1>This is a page</h1>
<?php
    // create a variable that we want to show in the main page
    $superhero = "batman";
?>
```

the above should output something like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is a page</h1>
  <p>batman</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google cannot see any of the PHP that created this page, just the completed HTML output